# Devise does not update all the custom fields in the User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a User model with following attributes, seller and estado (status).

```
t.string "estado", default: "pending"
t.boolean "seller", default: false
```

I have some validations for the User model:

```
validates :seller, default: false
validates :estado, inclusion: { in: %w(Accepted),
      message: "Status application: %{value}" }
```

I am tweeking devise, (in controller registrations, method create)trying to update these fields because of other conditions. For the seller it works, for the estado it does not

Here is the prove:

```
[4] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource.estado = "Accepted"
=> "Accepted"
[5] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource
=> #<User id: nil, email: "vendedor1@mail.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, shop_id: nil, seller: true, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, birthday: nil, nationality: nil, document_type: nil, document_number: nil, expiring_date: nil, estado: "pending", admin: false>
[6] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource.seller = false
=> false
[7] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource
=> #<User id: nil, email: "vendedor1@mail.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, shop_id: nil, seller: false, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, birthday: nil, nationality: nil, document_type: nil, document_number: nil, expiring_date: nil, estado: "pending", admin: false>
```

Why is not updating the value of estado? I see it in the console, but when I inspect resource, it's still pending.

I could allow the attributes commenting out this, as the first comment suggests:

```
  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
```

Comment: Do you have estado whitelisted in your devise allowable params?

Comment: you are right, it was commented out by device. What surprises me is that seller is allowed, and estado not